# How Huffman coding figured out the property that the codes are unique

Tags: encoding, compression, bit-manipulation, huffman-code

I have just read [this](http://jvns.ca/blog/2015/02/22/how-gzip-uses-huffman-coding/):

> This is where a really smart idea called Huffman coding comes in! The idea is that we represent our characters (like a, b, c, d, ….) with codes like
>
> ```
> a: 00
> b: 010
> c: 011
> d: 1000
> e: 1001
> f: 1010
> g: 1011
> h: 1111
> ```
>
> If you look at these carefully, you’ll notice something special! It’s that none of these codes is a prefix of any other code. So if we write down `010001001011` we can see that it’s `010 00 1001 011` or `baec`! There wasn’t any ambiguity, because `0` and `01` and `0100` don’t mean anything.

I get the gist of this, but I don't understand (a) how it was figured out, and (b) how you know it works, or (c) exactly what it means. Specifically this line describes it:

> So if we write down `010001001011` we can see that it’s `010 00 1001 011`....

I see that those are the codes, but I don't understand how you know not to read it as `0100 01 0010 11`. I see that these values aren't actually codes in the table. However, I don't see how you would ever figure this out! I would like to know how to discover this. If I were trying to tinker with codes and bits like this, I would do this:

1. Come up with a set of codes, like `10 100 1000 101 1001`
2. Try writing out some examples of the codes. So maybe an example is just concatenating the codes in order above: `1010010001011001`.
3. See if I can parse the codes. So `10` or oops, nope `101` also... Darnit, well maybe I can *add a priority* to the parsing of the code, and so `10` is higher priority than `101`. That gets me to `10 100 1000 10 x` nope that last 10 should be 101. Dangit.

So I would try adding different features like that priority function, or other things I can't think of at the moment, to see if it would help solve the problem.

I can't imagine how they would figure out that these codes in the Huffman coding could be uniquely parsed (I still don't see it, how it's actually true, I would have to write out some examples to see it, or, ... that's part of the question, how to *see* it's true, how to prove it even). Wondering if one could explain in more depth how it's proven to work, and how it was discovered (or how to discover something similar to it on your own).

Comment: *none of these codes is a prefix of any other code* -- if `10` code is possible than `101` code is *impossible* and vise versa. One can interpret the codes at pathes in [Huffman tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Huffman_coding) where `0` and `1` is direction switches and all codes (encoded letters) are leafs of the tree.

Comment: Your _Come up with a set of codes, like `10 100 1000 101 1001`_ is about as far from a prefix code as you can get. _Every_ one of them starts with the first code, `10`, so it is impossible to decode your code. If you look at the example code at the start of your question, you can see that _none_ of the other codes start with the first code, none of the subsequent codes start with the second code, and so on. So _that_ code can actually be decoded. At any point in the stream there is only one possible code that matches the bits starting there.

Comment: [this](https://www.cs.ucsb.edu/~franklin/20/assigns/prog6files/HuffmanEncoding.htm) was helpful.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Huffman code works by laying out data in a tree. If you have a binary tree, you can associate every leaf to a code by saying that left child corresponds to a bit at 0 and right child to a 1. The path that leads from the root to a leaf corresponds to a code in a not ambiguous way.

[image]

This works for any tree and the prefix property is based on the fact that a leaf is terminal. Hence, you cannot go to leaf (have a code) by passing though another leaf (by having another code be a prefix).

The basic idea of Huffman coding is that you can build trees in such a way that the depth of every node is correlated with the probability of appearance of the node (codes more likely to happen will be closer the root).

There are several algorithms to build such a tree. For instance, assume you have a set of items you want to code, say a..f. You must know the probabilities of appearance every item, thanks to either a model of the source or an analysis of the actual values (for instance by analysing the file to code).

Then you can:

1. sort the items by probability
2. pickup the two items with the lowest probability
3. remove these items, group them in a new compound node and assign one item to left child (code 0) and the other to right child (code 1).
4. The probability of the compound node is the sum of individual probabilities and insert this new node in the sorted item list.
5. goto 2 while the number of items is >1

For the previous tree, it may correspond to a set of probabilities

a (0.5) b (0.2) c (0.1) d (0.05) e (0.05) f (0.1)

Then you pick items with the lowest probability  (d and e), group them in a compound node (de) and get the new list

a (0.5) b (0.2) c (0.1) (de) (0.1) f (0.1)

And the successive item lists can be

a (0.5) b (0.2) c(de) (0.2) f (0.1)

a (0.5) b (0.2) (c(de))f (0.3)

a (0.5) b((c(de))f) (0.5)

a(b(((c(de))f)) 1.0

So the prefix property is insured by construction.